# Richtextbox and byte array

Tags: c#, udp, port, richtextbox, message

I'm working on program that should display all text on richtextbox that comming on my udp Port. But here is a problem. It displays a wrong text. For example: 
If i should get a "Hi" it displays "b¬ю". Code:

```
private void Chat(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            alive = true;
            try
            {
                while (alive)
                {
                    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
                    byte[] bytes = client.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    string message = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
                    string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        MB.AppendText("\r\n" + time + " " + message);
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                if (!alive)
                    return;
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Please help!

Comment: Looks like you have an encoding issue. How do you encode the data on the other end?

Comment: @GregorA.Lamche on other end it is all HEX. All packets that comming to me are hex.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here, but I know that you should encode and decode the strings/bytes the same way. So if you're using Encoding.Default.GetString() here, you should use Encoding.Default.GetBytes() on the other end.

Comment: @GregorA.Lamche a little more information. on other end it is a progam that i can't code. it is an app for some devices (i'm not totaly sure). And on the console app it displays perfectly with the same code. I have a problem with an app with richtextbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my decision.
Now it works perfectly.

```
string[] sep = { "\0" };
                    string[] res = message.Split(sep,StringSplitOptions.None);
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        MB.AppendText("\r\n" + time + " " + res[1]); 
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from your UDP charset encoding. Try to write:

```
MB.AppendText("Hello");
```

If its still apperaing encoded it may be cause of the richtextbox but I'm mostly sure that is caused by the channel encoding.

Comment: "Hello" is apperaing great. Now i'm sure thats cause encoding.

Comment: @tony try Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes)